# IIS 6 "Maximum request length exceeded." trigger before Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

I'm using IIS 6 to host my Asp.net site. I'm having

> "Maximum request length exceeded."

error. I fixed it on IIS 7 but on IIS 6, Asp.net error triggers before going into the `Global.asax` Application_Error. I'm just redirecting to a custom error page in `Application_Error`. Please let me know what I'm missing here.

**Here is the fix I used in IIS 7 webconfig**

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="UploadError.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

The solution above won't work on IIS 6! I need to do it in `Application_Error` on `Global.asax`. Which is not triggering before `Maximum request length exceeded.`

Comment: did you change in web.config?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

Comment: What was the fix for IIS7? You can increase the maximum request length with some simple changes to the web.config.

Comment: Well, yes I know I could change the file size limitation. But I want to show the custom error message instead of asp.net default error.

Comment: @HardCode: You may want to rephrase your question. Nowhere in your post do you state that your intentions are to trap and display the error.

Comment: @Cory: Application_Error explains itself! and I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of:
[Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

This thread contains the solution for both IIS6 and IIS7 on handling maximum request length exceptions

For redirecting to custom error pages, in your Web.Config, use the following:

```
<configuration>
...

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
                  defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" />

    ...
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

where "~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" is the path to your error page.

Comment: I want to redirect to custom error page! I don't see the solution. By the way I fixed it on IIS 7, using httpErrors in the webconfig.

Comment: I expanded my answer to also address your primary problem of not displaying the custom error page.

Comment: Your solution works for general error. But I'm looking to show specific error.

Comment: Use something like the following:

<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/temp/readme.txt" />
</customErrors>

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `security` block you would also need to change the `system.web\httpRuntime` which has a `maxRequestLength` attribute.

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192" />
```

More [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)